# Equations above and below space should fix

Tags: spacing, equations

My requirement is to fix all display equation above and below space to some value (e.g., 18pt from text base to equation base). For this, I am using the below tags:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip 6\p@
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

It was working well for simple equations, but if any equations having fractions (`\frac`), `\sum`, `\int` (these symbols having any limits) etc, then the space was varying, but I need `18pts` should fix what ever comes in equation content. How can I achieve this? Please suggest...

Here is my usage:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip 6\p@
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\makeatother
\normalsize
\begin{document}

Cincinnati for their help with this book, especially
Zvi Biener, Vanessa Carbonell, Anthony Chemero, Valerie
Hardcastle, John McEvoy, Thomas Polger, Robert Richardson, Robert
Skipper, and George Uetz in biology. Guilherme Sanches de Oliveira
provided research assistance and help with indexing. I also
received tremendously helpful feedback from the graduate students
and faculty who participated in my seminar on idealization in the
autumn of 2014, including some of those named above, as well as
Frank Faries, Maurice Lamb, Vicente Raja Galian, Walter
including some of Stepanenko,
\begin{align}
a+b=c
\end{align}

Cincinnati for their help with this book, especially
Zvi Biener, Vanessa Carbonell, Anthony Chemero, Valerie
Hardcastle, John McEvoy, Thomas Polger, Robert Richardson, Robert
Skipper, and George Uetz in biology. Guilherme Sanches de Oliveira
provided research assistance and help with indexing. I also
received tremendously helpful feedback from the graduate students
and faculty who participated in my seminar on idealization in the
autumn of 2014, including some of those named above, as well as
Frank Faries, Maurice Lamb, Vicente Raja Galian, Walter
including some of Stepanenko,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\displaystyle\int\sum1+2}{3+4}a+b=c
\end{align}
Cincinnati for their help with this book, especially
Zvi Biener, Vanessa Carbonell, Anthony Chemero, Valerie
Hardcastle, John McEvoy, Thomas Polger, Robert Richardson, Robert
Skipper, and George Uetz in biology. Guilherme Sanches de Oliveira
provided research assistance and help with indexing. I also
received tremendously helpful feedback from the graduate students
and faculty who participated in my seminar on idealization in the
autumn of 2014, including some of those named above, as well as
Frank Faries, Maurice Lamb, Vicente Raja Galian, Walter
including some of Stepanenko,

\end{document}
```

If any fraction comes inside a display math, then the text base to denominator of the fraction base should come as 18pts, please suggest...

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Any suggestions for my requirement...still I am waiting